# Symfony 5 , Error deleting object : creating new id instead of deleting object in One to one relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, associations, symfony5

I have an `OneToOne` association with entities called `Record` and `AnalyseOfCause`.

When I send the record entity to my controller and **i want to delete** `AnalyseOfCause` related to it
instead of deleting `AnalyseOfCause` object it just keep same object and **change his ID by giving a new last ID and not deleting it**.

*PS : When I do not call `Record` object at all **and want to delete `AnalyseOfCause` directly** by ***sending id of of `AnalyseOfCause`*** and finding him directly in another function it works. So I don't understand what is the problem.*

*( I observed that when I do in function find `analyseOfCause` object by doctrine->repo->find(id)
it does delete but one I call the record object in same function even deleting was working stops working. And what is strange is when i make ctrl+z and come back to working version it still do not work, so strange behavior )*
*PS: Not for those 2 objects but for other objects I use Softdeletable bundle in my app. I don't know if it does anything to do with this problem..*

Thanks at advance for your help :)

[image: controller: code php to delete]

[image: dumping the analyse of cause object]

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are  using two entityManager instances ($entitymanager and $em). Try using only one of those.

Comment: I've edit the question. The problem is not this

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using two entityManager instances ($entitymanager and $em). Try using only one of those.

For example:

If you use paramConverters:

```php
public function hard_delete(Request $request, ComplainRecord $complainRecord, EntityManagerInterface $em) {

   $getAnalyseOfCause = $complainRecord->getAnalyseOfCause();

   $em->remove($getAnalyseOfCause)
   $em->flush();

   ...

}
```

If you only use the 'raw' ID (and no injected entityManager):

```php
public function hard_delete(Request $request) {


   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $repository = $em->getRepository(GetAnalyseOfCause::class);
   $analyseOfCause = $repository->find($request->get('slug'));

   $em->remove($analyseOfCause);
   $em->flush();

   ...

}
```